# Wildfly Web Service JAXB Unmarshall Error when coming from .net client

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap, jaxb

I have a web service from CXF where defaultElementForm="unqualified", hosted in Wildfly 8, using latest Java 7.  When I have java clients connect, they work fine, if generated from CXF, because their soap message contents look like:

```
 <ns:MyCall1 xmlns:ns="http://example.com/">
      <MyCall2>
...
```

The .net clients, are the exact same message, with only one difference, and this does not work:

```
<MyCall1 xmlns="http://example.com/">
    <MyCall2 xmlns="">
```

...

Unfortunately, the reason it is failing, is it looks like JAXB is ignoring xmlns="" completely, so it thinks the namespace is still http://example.com/, which doesn't match the "" unqualified gets you.  If I changed it to xmlns="a", then it gets an error saying a doesn't match expected namespace "", but if I leave it as "", it says http://example.com/ does not match expected "". So it's ignoring the xmlns="" which is needed to clear the default namespace.

There must be some setting, or some way to make the java web service through jaxb interpret that properly. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, if anyone else (probably no one) hits this issue.  It's fixed in Wildfly 8.2, but happened in 8.0 and 8.1...so must've been some kind of Wildfly or jax-ws or jax-b issue.  In any case, latest release has it fixed thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

We just encountered a similar problem with Wildfly and a .Net server.  We worked around it by changing the WSDL we feed to `wsdl2java` so that the problem elements were qualified rather than unqualified.
So we changed this:

```
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/messageresult/v200">
    ---snip---
    <s:complexType name="SubmissionResponseType">
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="ID" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="StatusText" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  ---snip---
</s:schema>
```

To this:

```
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/messageresult/v200">
    ---snip---
    <s:complexType name="SubmissionResponseType">
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="qualified" name="ID" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="qualified" name="StatusText" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  ---snip---
</s:schema>
```

Comment: That will work and provide interoperability to .net, if you are able to change the schema to be qualified for elements (and want it that way), but it makes the XML message quite a bit longer and requires changing the wsdl.  

An alternate solution, is just do a soap handler and convert the soap message from .net style to our format if necessary - very poor though, I wish had a better one, you'd think would be a common issue, and seems like weird issue with jaxb/wildfly somewhere along line.